# load files from executable jar

Tags: java, resources, executable-jar

In my application I have a button which loads the index.html from folder src/resources/help/. The folder help contains html files. When I work from eclipse it works normally, but when I tried to load this file from executable jar it can't load file to browser. 
I load the file like that.

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resources/help/index.html");
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(url.toURI());
```

What should I do? Should I extract help folder? How can I do that?

Path on runtime:

- from eclipse - `file:/C:/Users/MyName/workspace/ProjectName/bin/resources/help/index.html`
- from jar - `rsrc:resources/help/index.html`

Comment: Does the jar contain that file at that path?

Comment: Yes the folder help is in jar..

Comment: The folder help is. Is the parent folder resources there?

Comment: Yep. resources/help/index.html. Also my classes are in folder visual. Folders resources and visual are in same the level...

Comment: Prepend a `/` to the path.

Comment: Not helps. NullPointerException!!

Comment: ok from eclipse: file:/C:/Users/MyName/workspace/ProjectName/bin/resources/help/index.html and from jar-rsrc:resources/help/index.html

Comment: Problem is that URI in Jar shows only position inside jar structure so browser cant know where `resource` directory is. Also even if it could know it probably wouldn't be able to read it because it is archived inside jar.

Comment: So what i should  do?

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of your html files. Simple solution would be to put them outside of jar file, lets say in some subdirectory of directory where jar is placed.

Comment: The html files, are help files from my application.. I'll try to put them outside...